# How do I make my table maintain a certain width when screen size is shrinking?

Tags: css

while the screen size starts to get around the mobile area, my table(above footer)shrinks down to the size of the content that's inside of it. It stuck out of the form a little so I added overflow-x: scroll;

This however does not fix the main issue which is the table shrinking to fit the content. I do want it to shrink for tablets but I think this should happen all the way up to a min-width of 635px;

At which point I would like the overflow-x: scroll; to take effect and the table to stop shrinking. For some reason overflow-x: scroll only kicks in at a min-width of 388px;(Even though this property is in a media query at min-width 686px)

I tried using min-width on the table. While this keeps it from shrinking any further it pushes it out of the form. Any ideas?

https://jsfiddle.net/r4ptsohe/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>Careers | Kane Concrete & Construction LLC</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/careers.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo|Bitter|Lato|Montserrat|Noto+Sans|Open+Sans|Poppins|Roboto|Sarabun|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Asap|Krub|Oxygen|Rajdhani|Staatliches|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="careers-wrapper">
   <nav>
    <div class="logo">
     <i class="fab fa-accusoft"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="nav">
     <div class="ham-menu">
      <div class="m1" id="m1"></div>
      <div class="m2" id="m2"></div>
      <div class="m3" id="m3"></div>
     </div>
     <ul>
      <li class="after"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="about.html#services">Services</a></li>
      <li class="after"><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>

   <h1>Join Our Team</h1>
  </div> 
 </header>

 <section class="form">
 <h2>We're Hiring</h2>

  <form action="" method="" id="form">
   <h3>General Information</h3>
   <div class="row row-1">
    <input type="text" name="First" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="Last" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="text" name="SSN" placeholder="SSN">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-2">
    <input type="text" name="Address" placeholder="Address">
   </div>
   
   <div class="row row-3">
    <input type="text" name="City" placeholder="City">
    <input type="text" name="State" placeholder="State" class="middle">
    <input type="text" name="Zipcode" placeholder="Zipcode">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-4">
    <div class="label"><label for="Primary-Phone" class="row-4">Primary-Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="Primary-Phone" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx">
    <div class="label"><label for="Cell-Phone" class="row-4">Cell-Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="Cell-Phone" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-5">
    <label>Are you 18 years old or older?</label>
    <div class="radio">
     <input type="radio" name="ageYears" value="Yes" id="ageYearsYes">
     <label for="ageYearsYes">Yes</label>
     <input type="radio" name="ageYears" value="No" required="" id="ageYearsNo">
     <label for="ageYearsNo">No</label>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row row-6">
    <div class="label"><label>Desired Wage:</label></div>
    <input type="text" id="wage-desired">
    <div class="label"><label>Available Start Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" id="start-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-7">
    <div class="col">
     <label>Are you legally authorized to work in the U.S?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="legally" value="Yes" id="legally-yes">
      <label for="legally-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="legally" value="No" required="" id="legally-no">
      <label for="legally-no">No</label>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
     <label>Are you willing to submit to a drug test?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="drug-test" value="Yes" id="drug-yes">
      <label for="drug-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="drug-test" value="No" required="" id="drug-no">
      <label for="drug-no">No</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row row-8">
    <div class="col">
     <label>Have you ever been convicted of a crime? If yes, please explain.</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="crime-answer" value="Yes" id="crime-yes">
      <label for="crime-yes" id="crime-yes">Yes</label>
      <input type="radio" name="crime-answer" value="No" required="" id="crime-no">
      <label for="crime-no">No</label>
      <textarea name="crime-info" cols="70" rows="4" class="crime-textarea"></textarea>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
     <label class="">How did you hear about this job?</label>
     <div class="radio">
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="friend" id="friend">
      <label for="friend">friend</label>
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="online" id="online">
      <label for="friend">online</label>
      <input type="radio" name="friend" value="other" id="other">
      <label for="other">other</label>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

   <hr>
   <h3>Employment History</h3>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <div class="row row-9">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer">Current/Recent Employer:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-10">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-phone">Phone #</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-phone">
    <div class="label"><label for="employer-address">Address:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="employer-address">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-11">
    <div class="label"><label for="hire-date">Hired Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="hire-date">
    <div class="label"><label for="end-date">End Date:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="end-date">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-12">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-title">Job Title:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-title">
    <div class="label"><label for="job-responsibilities">Job Responsibilities:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="job-responsibilities">
   </div>

   <div class="row row-13">
    <div class="label"><label for="wage-rate">Wage Rate:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="wage-rate">
    <div class="label"><label for="reason-left">Reason For Leaving:</label></div>
    <input type="text" name="reason-left">
   </div>

   <hr>

   <h3>Refrences</h3>

   <div class="table-wrap">
    <table>
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>NAME</th>
       <th>RELATIONSHIP</th>
       <th>COMPANY</th>
       <th>PHONE NUMBER</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refName1" name="refName1" placeholder="John Doe" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refRel1" name="refRel1" placeholder="Relationship" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refComp1" name="refComp1" placeholder="Company Name" required="">
       </td>
       <td>
        <input type="text" id="refPhone1" name="refPhone1" placeholder="Phone #">
       </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
  </form>
 </section>

 <section class="footer">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <div class="links">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Quick Links</span></h1>

     <a href="index.html">Home</a>
     <a href="about.html">About</a>
     <a href="about.html#services">Services</a>
     <a href="careers.html">Careers</a>
     <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
     <a href="contact.html#quote">Quote</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="social">
    <div class="inner">
     <h1><span>Social</span></h1>

     <i class="fab fa-linkedin"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-facebook"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>
     <i class="fab fa-twitter-square"><a href="#" class="social-net"></a></i>

     <button name="msg">Send</button>
     <textarea name="msg" class="footer-textarea" cols="45" rows="5" placeholder="Send us some feedback..."></textarea>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="contact">
    <div class="inner" class="wrap">
     <h1><span>Contact</span></h1>

     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Matt</span></p>
     <p>(208)546-7827 - <span class="dark">Keegan</span></p>
     <p><span class="dark">Address</span> - P.O. Box 50860 IF, ID 83405</p>
     <p><span class="dark">Email</span> - KaneConcrete@fake.com</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="copyright"><span>&copy; 2019 - Kane Concrete & Construction | ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</span></div>
 </section>
 <script src="../script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
@media (max-width: 686px) {
  .table-wrap {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  .table-wrap table {
    min-width: 685px;
  }
}
```

... seems to do the job.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/wg8au46o/

Comment: Thank you!!! Why not use overflow-x: scroll instead of auto? Both work? what's the diff?

Comment: @Randy, because `overflow: scroll` displays a useless scrollbar when it's not required, in a good number of browser versions. The two values act similarly in browser versions which paint the scrollbar on scroll event alone.